# " choco install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools " Fails Error: The install of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, visual-studio-2017, choco

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco install visualstudio2017-workload-vctools
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
visualstudio2017-workload-vctools
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading visualstudio2017-workload-vctools 1.3.2... 100%

visualstudio2017-workload-vctools v1.3.2 [Approved]
visualstudio2017-workload-vctools package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package visualstudio2017-workload-vctools wants to run 'ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): a

ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.
The install of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - visualstudio2017-workload-vctools (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Comment: I tried to intsall node.js and got this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`

Comment: Run CMD as Administrator

Answer (score 6):

looks like your visualstudio installer is out of date.

try to upgrade installer

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe"

then (as administrator)

> choco upgrade -y visualstudio2017-workload-vctools

Comment: I got this  ERROR: Unable to detect any supported Visual Studio product. You may try passing --installPath or both --productId and --channelId parameters.
The upgrade of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Comment: Restarted my PC in-between steps to clear out idle installation instance. This removed the error I was seeing when trying to run 'choco upgrade -y visualstudio2017-workload-vctools'. Tyvm!

Answer (score 4):

Try opening CMD or PowerShell with "Run as Administrator" and run `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`.

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

As other people suggested, running this command solved it... at least for me: `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`

I'll add one thing and it's that you may need to close and open PowerShell while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the year on the command to match the version os VS installed. In my case I used: `choco upgrade -y visualstudio2022-workload-vctools`